# Additional kinds of lenses for Monad/MonadPlus/etc?

Tags: haskell, lenses

So, the `Functor` makes a 1-1 logical dataflow - a `Lens`.
The `Applicative` makes a n-1 logical dataflow - a `Traversal`.
The `Applicative` on the `Choice` `Profunctor` makes a "break to parts" mechanism - a `Prism`.

Are there any interesting known structures involving a `Monad`, `MonadPlus`, etc capabilities or some other subsets of `Profunctors`?

Comment: "Functor makes a 1-1 relation". Does it?

Comment: `Functor` allows us to apply a pure function when declaring a `Lens`, thus presenting a _logical_ "1-1" dataflow. The `Applicative` allows us to "merge boxes" ("n-1"), and the `Prism` gives us a way to break things.

Comment: Here is an interesting thread where the feature request necessitates the type `forall m. (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> s -> m t`. The resulting discussion is about why that type doesn't play well with the lens ecosystem. https://github.com/ekmett/lens/issues/109